# What is the principle of UICollectionView flowLayout

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

In a *Horizontal* UICollectionView and the itemWidth is fixed I set `minimumLineSpacing = someValue` it achieve the desired results, But when the itemWidth is randomed，set the `minimumLineSpacing = someValue` it dosen't achieve the desired results, must set `minimumInteritemSpacing = someValue`.

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/fmxfmx/UICollectionViewDemo)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var screenSize: CGRect!
    var screenWidth: CGFloat!
    var screenHeight: CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        screenWidth = screenSize.width
        screenHeight = screenSize.height

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 3, height: screenWidth / 3)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.frame.size.width = screenWidth / 3
        cell.frame.size.height = screenWidth / 3

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```